# How to use external data range for a Google sheet pivot?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, import, pivot-table

I'd like to use another spreadsheet's data as the data range for a pivot table.

In order to import data from another spreadsheet, one can use the impotrange function.

But can it be imported directly into a pivot table?

Such an attempt states it's not a valid range:

[image: No import for Pivot]

Comment: I had a déjà vu: I'm pretty sure that somewhere I read and answer a very similar question.

Comment: I remember now. The same question was posted in the Google Docs Help Community in Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to import range by adding a formula in the Pivot Table editor, you have to add there a reference to a range in the current spreadsheet.

If you don't want that the sheet with the imported data be visible you could hide it.

Another alternative is to use Google Data Studio. Depending on the purpose of your pivot table, you could use GDS to "explore" a data connection to the source spreadsheet or to create a report.